# Data storage in Firestore For Offline App

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore as a NoSQL databse in my Android app. I want to store data locally in my Android device and avoid syncing with Firestore server in the initial stages of app. Is is possible for the data to persist on device even if app or mobile device restarts without syncing with Firestore database? If yes then how do I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to store data locally in my android device and avoid syncing with Firestore server in the initial stages of app.

According to the official documentation regarding [Firestore offline persistens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default. To disable persistence, set the PersistenceEnabled option to false.

And to answer the second question:

> Is is possible for the data to persist on device even if app or mobile device restarts without syncing with Firestore database?

Yes it is. This kind of persistens is called *disk persistence*, which means that recently listened data (as well as any pending writes from the app to the database) are persisted to disk. The data in this cache survives app restarts, and phone reboots.